# Is it possible to make a macro with \label?

Tags: macros, cross-referencing

I'm not very experienced with LaTeX and I'm having trouble when trying to define a macro to include some images. I want to do it this way because I'm trying to take notes using LaTeX and I need to type it quickly. The macro is:

```
\newcommand{\capeps}[3]{\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center} 
\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{./figures/#1.eps}
\caption{#2} 
\label{fig:#3} 
\end{center} 
\end{figure}}
```

but I can't make it recognize the label. Do you know what's the problem with this?

Comment: Works like a charm for me. Maybe you could include a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: What @Silex said! Besides: you might want to replace the `center` environment with `\centering`. [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: What is your parameter of `\ref`? For `\capeps{xxx}{yyy}{zzz}` it has to be `\ref{fig:zzz}` and not just `\ref{zzz}`.

Comment: thank you for the answers, I didn't expected to be so quick :)
Well, it kind of work for me, but when I use the label I get "??" instead of the reference number.

Comment: ohh, your are right. My error was in the \ref part, the macro was good. Thank you very much.